# How to make method argument evaluation lazy?

Tags: java

I have a debug log statement in my code to which I am passing a result of costly method call.

```
log.debug("Data - {}", obj.costlyMethodCall());
```

Now, even if debug logging is disabled, **obj.costlyMethodCall()** will always be evaluated to be passed as method argument.

One way to mitigate this is to have a explicit check if debug logging is enabled

```
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
  log.debug("Data - {}", obj.costlyMethodCall());
}
```

But this reduces code readability.

Is there any better way to make invocation of **obj.costlyMethodCall()** lazy or conditional here?

Comment: Use a `Supplier` or explicitly check if debug is enabled. It reduces readability, but only if it's used a lot. If it's used a lot, that indicates you have design issues if you're always logging expensive method calls.

Answer (score 5):

Usually this is solved by having a method accepting something similar to a `Supplier` instead of a concrete `Object` so that you can pass in something like

```
log.debug("Data - {}", () -> obj.costlyMethodCall());
```

where `log.debug` is something like

```
public void debug(String message, Supplier<Object> supplier) {
    Object value = supplier.get(); // costlyMethodCall is only called here
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Using a lambda doesn't improve readability much, imho.

Comment: I definitely like it more than making a one-line log-statement into a three-line if-with-log-statement, especially because another `if` increases the complexity of that method and needs testing to make sure that the logging statement itself does not produce errors when objects are suddenly `null` etc.

Comment: The lambda moves the `if` down, so the test complexity doesn not change. (kind of obfuscating what happens)

Comment: Well, of course, but it moves the condition if the debug mode is enabled out of "my" code so I don't have to have a specific test for enabled and disabled debug mode - only that the correct values are passed to the logger

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you could use lamdba expression to delay that. New versions of logger use this approach, like log4j 2.4. You don't need to provide new methods, just use newer logging API if you can.

You can do the following:

```
log.debug("Data - {}", () -> obj.costlyMethodCall());
```

They added this in recent logger where you need to delay String usage, without polluting your code with the `if(log.isDebugEnabled())`...

You pass a `Supplier` that will return the Strings, only once called.

You can check this link if you need to: https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2015/09/16/a-gentle-introduction-to-the-log4j-api-and-lambda-basics/

Comment: Surely that's just making the string evaluation lazy, not `costlyMethodCall()`?

Comment: I'm updating :)

Comment: The `toString()` of a `Supplier` doesn't necessarily invoke the supplier.

Comment: @Andy Turner What do you mean ?

Comment: See the Ideone example in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are already extensively bought into a logging framework, defining your own methods, as suggested by [Smutje](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63168630/3788176), may not be a practical option.

Instead, define a static method something like:

```
static <T> Supplier<T> lazy(Supplier<? extends T> delegate) {
  return new Supplier<T>() {
    @Override public T get() { return delegate.get(); }
    @Override public String toString() { return Objects.toString(get()); }
  };
}
```

Then provide this as an argument to your call:

```
log.debug("Data - {}", lazy(() -> obj.costlyMethodCall()));
```

If you don't provide a `Supplier` which overrides `toString()`, the logging library can't (necessarily) know that it needs to evaluate the supplier to build the `toString()`. [Ideone example](https://ideone.com/9fl3kg).

Comment: Smutje does not define a new logging method... New logging framework, like log4j 2.4 provides this methods. So, no need to define custom method.

Comment: @RUAROThibault no specific logging framework is mentioned, nvm a version.